# Power multiplication rule in complex number case

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to search an example such that $(z^a)^b \neq z^{ab}$ , where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers and $z$ is non zero complex number. I am totally blankl how to approach this ? May be it is not possible to find such example.

Comment: To begin with, what does $z^a$ mean?

Comment: z power a ......

Comment: And what is that? For instance, what is $i^\pi$?

Comment: As @learning123 points out, the “rules of exponents” that you learned in high school are valid only when the base is a nonnegative real number, and the exponent is real. If I may inveigh a bit, I’ve seen that one of the defects of high-school teaching is that insufficient attention is paid to the domain of definition of functions; the failure of the above rule may be considered to lie in that broader class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a false-proof that $1 = -1$:

$$1 = i^4$$
$$\implies (1)^{\frac{1}{2}} = (i^4)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\implies 1 = i^2 = -1$$

As you can probably see, the reason this proof is wrong is because $(i^4)^{\frac{1}{2}} \neq i^{4\cdot\frac{1}{2}}$.

Similar example: $(e^{2\pi i})^{1/2}\neq e^{\pi i}$.